# Solr data sources

Tags: solr

I got a somewhat vague question about Apache Solr. After doing some reading, I still do not understand from where it gets the data it uses for search. Does it connect to some remote server or a file system and searches there? Or, does it search within the data I have indexed in the Solr server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLR searches the data that is indexed in SOLR index.